# AngularJS NanoScroller after ng-repeat doesn't show

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scrollbar, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've been trough many posts on stackoverflow but I didn't manage to find the answer yet. I have a jQuery scrollbar plugin (nanoscroll), and I want it to update after a ng-repeat.
As many posts here suggests, I've used a directive like this :

```
myApp.directive("postRender", function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        jQuery('.nano').nanoScroller({preventPageScrolling: true});
    }
});
```

and then I have something like :

```
<div class="nano"> <!-- my scrollable area -->
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items" post-render>
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
    Some content here...
</div> <!-- my scrollable area -->
```

The problem is that (I have no idea why), if the content is just a little bit bigger than the available size for the `.nano div` then the scrollbar doesn't show.

I believe that AngularJS doesn't wait to insert the content after the controller before trying to update nanoscroller and that this content is added after the posrt-render directive. 
By the way, I doubt that this problem comes from NanoScroller because when I hit F11 two times (full screen and back to normal mode), whithout any DOM modification, the scrollbar appears.

Thanks,
hilnius

__*_*_ ANSWER

Finally i found the solution. For those who wonder, it is necessary to use the $timeout service. Like that :

```
myApp.directive('postRender',['$timeout', function (timer) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            timer(function () {
                    jQuery('.nano').nanoScroller({preventPageScrolling: true})
                 }
                 , 0);
        }
    }
}]);
```

Altough I found a solution I'm still not aware of the issue that was there. I believe it's because the angular directive wasn't waiting for the DOM to be completely modified, maybe there were time concerns.

Comment: It's better to post answer as 'Answer' and mark it as Answer :)

Answer (score 0):

OP found the solution.

It is necessary to use the **$timeout service**. Like this:

```
myApp.directive('postRender',['$timeout', function (timer) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            timer(function () {
                    jQuery('.nano').nanoScroller({preventPageScrolling: true})    
                 }, 0);
        }
    }
}]);
```